# javascript or css trick to group spans without separating them when one reaches the edge of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

so we have three spans and a parent span

```
<span id="parent"><span1></span><span2></span><span3></span></span>
```

when one of the spans reach the right end of the browser, it moves down, leaving its siblings behind. Are there any tricks here on how to keep these spans together that if one moves down, the others will follow? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#parent {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```